# How can I know if my web application is open or closed inside a service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

It is possible to know if my web application has anyone tab open inside a service worker?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  As far as I know, service workers dont listen to those kinds of events

Comment: I would like show push notifications only if my web application is open.

Comment: only when the web application is open?  that defeats the purpose of having push notifications.  

Push notifications are commonly used when the user is NOT on the page/site so when they receive it, you can drive the users back to the site.

Comment: look at the client object OTTOMH there is something like .hasFocus() and if not you can request foregrounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this solve my problem.

```
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {

  self.client.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'})
  .then((clients) => {
    if(clients && clients.length > 0) {
      // Show notification
    }
  });

}, false);
```